# Software Arcitecture Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, architecture, geolocation

Can someone explain to me how to solve the following problem in Flutter: I want to create an app that shows my current location on a map and the corresponding weather at the location. My question about this is how do I use the geolocation plugin so that I can only query this once and pass the corresponding values to both widgets.
This is my geolocation:

```
 import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class LocationService {
  final StreamController<Position> _positionController = StreamController<Position>();
  late StreamSubscription<Position> _positionStreamSubscription;
  late Position _lastPosition; // Stores the last position
  final double minDistance = 10.0; // Minimum distance (5 meters)

  Stream<Position> get positionStream => _positionController.stream;

  LocationService() {
    _lastPosition = Position(
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      timestamp: DateTime.now(),
      accuracy: 0,
      altitude: 0,
      heading: 0,
      speed: 0,
      speedAccuracy: 0, // Provide a value for speedAccuracy
    ); // Initial position with required parameters

    _positionStreamSubscription = Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((position) {
      double distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
        _lastPosition.latitude,
        _lastPosition.longitude,
        position.latitude,
        position.longitude,
      );

      if (distance >= minDistance) {
        _positionController.sink.add(position);
        _lastPosition = position; // Update the last position
      }
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    _positionController.close();
    _positionStreamSubscription.cancel();
  }
}
```

This is my Map example from Flutter :still needs to be adjusted

```
import 'dart:async'; // Import the dart:async library
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {

  const MapSample(Position pos,{Key? key}) : super(key: key); // Corrected constructor

  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();
     
  static const CameraPosition currentPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  static const CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: currentPosition,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        label: const Text('To the lake!'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    await controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
  }
}
```

And this is my Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'map.dart'; // Importiere die map.dart-Datei
import 'geolocator.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Geolocation App'),
        ),
        body: LocationWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LocationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationWidgetState createState() => _LocationWidgetState();
}

class _LocationWidgetState extends State<LocationWidget> {
  LocationService _locationService = LocationService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _locationService = LocationService(); // Initialisiere den LocationService
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _locationService.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<Position?>(
            stream: _locationService.positionStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
  final Position position = snapshot.data!;

  return ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  MapSample()), // Navigiere zur MapScreen-Seite
              );
            },
            child: Text('Open Map'),
  );
} else if (snapshot.hasError) {
  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
} else {
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
//'Latitude: ${position.latitude}, Longitude: ${position.longitude}',
            },
          ),
            ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  MapSample()), // Navigiere zur MapScreen-Seite
              );
            },
            child: Text('Open Map'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! What specific issue are you experiencing at the moment? Is it with the permissioning?